# Flat List - index manipulating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to manipulating flatlist index. I would like to convert flat list index to messageID

My main request , I would like to change flatlist item data

I have json array like this;

```
 this.state.messages = [
      {
        "date": "09:55",
        "longDate": "22/10/2018",
        "message": "ghjghj",
        "messageID": 157,
        "senderID": 1,
        "showLongDate": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "uri": ""
      },
      {
        "date": "09:56",
        "longDate": "22/10/2018",
        "message": "rtyrtyrt",
        "messageID": 158,
        "senderID": 1,
        "showLongDate": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "uri": ""
      }
    ]
```

my flat list;

```
 <FlatList
  ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}           
  data={this.state.messages}
  renderItem={({item, index})=>(
    <View><Text>{item.message}</Text></View> 
  )}
  removeClippedSubviews={true} 
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing} 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.messageID.toString()} 
  onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}  
  extraData={this.state}   
/>
```

Comment: Could you please give more insights of what you are trying to acheive ?

Comment: Can we see your FlatList  component implementation

Comment: I am making chat app on react-native. I add always head of array when I take new messages on socket.io. So my array and flatlist index always changing and start at 0. I would like to change my flatlist item without index , or I would like to create index with messageID

Comment: Why don't you change this item.message.toString() to this item.messageID.toString() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
  ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}           
  data={list}
  renderItem={({item, index})=>(
    <View /><Text>{item.message}</Text></View> 
  )}
  removeClippedSubviews={true} 
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing} 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.message.toString()} 
  onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}  
  extraData={this.state}   
/>
```

Comment: This is not what I want

Comment: You should provide enough context to the question. Initially I thought the this.state.messages wasn't a list. Now I see that it is a list

Comment: remove the first closing <View /> and replace with <View>